# Don't you think they'll find it hard/difficult to trust you again?

Tags: word-choice

> Don't you think they'll find it hard/difficult to trust you again?

Are "hard" and "difficult" completely interchangeable here? Would native speakers even think of which of them to use in this type of context?

Comment: Yes, they're totally interchangeable, with "difficult" sounding slightly more "high-brow". I'd expect a sociolinguistic analysis to show that "difficult" correlates weakly with more education.

Answer (score 1):

In other contexts, hard and difficult might mean different things, as hard can mean dense, resistant to impact, etc.

In this case, hard is "not easy" which is the same as "difficult".

Answer (score 0):

The usage of "hard/difficult" here is unnecessary since in this context they are synonyms.

So either:

> Don't you think they'll find it hard to trust you again?

or

> Don't you think they'll find it difficult to trust you again?

could be used as they both convey the same meaning and could be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

Not a native speaker but you can probably think about in which contexts you would refer to something as hard. Like if an object is heavy, impenetrable, seemingly immutable, resistant and so on. So given that you often describe things that are hard from the perspective of dealing with them in a way that addresses that property that resists a change to it's state, you likely come across lots of examples where hard implies a challenge and thus where hard and difficult imply the same thing.